# How to use inject outside class in pure function in angular v14?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to inject my `FooService` and use it only when I click on the button.

But I got this error:

```
Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context (a constructor, a factory function or a field initializer)
```

Is there a way to make it work by `inject` will be in a separate function?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j3e5hg?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffoo.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
import { Component, inject, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { FooService } from './foo.service';

const load = () => {
  const foo = inject(FooService);
  foo.doSome();
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `in app! <button (click)="onClick()">click </button>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  onClick() {
    load();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what is your end goal instead of asking about what you think is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this with [runInContext](https://angular.io/api/core/EnvironmentInjector#runincontext) available from Angular 14.1 onwards.

```
const load = () => {
  const foo = inject(FooService);
  foo.doSome();
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `in app! <button (click)="onClick()">click </button>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  constructor(private injector: EnvironmentInjector) {}

  onClick() {
    this.injector.runInContext(() => {
      load(); // in this context, injections are allowed. 
    });
  }
}
```